# Get weekday from date picker then show/hide class

Tags: javascript

Lets say a restaurant has brunch only on Saturday and Sunday and they are open late Friday and Saturday. For the reservation form I want it to show/hide time options depending on the day of the week. I found this script to get the day of the week but I need help with the conditional statement to select the class and the onchange event. I've created a class "brunch" for Sat & Sun and class "openlate" for Friday & Saturday

```
<script>
$( "#date" ).datepicker({
    'dateFormat':'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateText){
        var seldate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        seldate = seldate.toDateString();
        seldate = seldate.split(' ');
        var weekday=new Array();
            weekday['Mon']="Monday";
            weekday['Tue']="Tuesday";
            weekday['Wed']="Wednesday";
            weekday['Thu']="Thursday";
            weekday['Fri']="Friday";
            weekday['Sat']="Saturday";
            weekday['Sun']="Sunday";
        var dayOfWeek = weekday[seldate[0]];

    }
});
</script>

<input name="date" id="date" value="" data-gdatetimepicker-format="m/d/Y" type="text" data-fieldtype="gdatetimepicker" data-start_view="d" />

<label>Time:</label>
<select name="time" id="time">
    <option value="11:00 AM" class="brunch">11:00 AM</option>
    <option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
    <option value="11:00 PM" class="frisat">11:00 PM</option>
</select>
```

Comment: so once they pick a date you want to add a class to the select element?

Comment: Here's a protip to at least make things easier for you -> [**Date.getDay()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

Comment: I just want to show or hide options depending on the date.

Comment: I don't see your "brunch" and "openlate" classes. What help do you need with the conditional statement?